# Qual a diferença de tipos de exportação em React?

Tags: javascript, react, módulo-ecmascript

Sou um iniciante em React e estou com uma dúvida bem simples, eu quero saber qual a diferença a criação e exportação de um componente, acontece que já vi 3 formas diferentes e quero saber se existe diferença entre elas.

```js
//Primeira forma:
export default function Home() {</
    return()
}

//Segunda forma:
function Home(){
  return()
}
export default Home;

//Terceira forma:
const Home = () => {
   return()
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade, sua pergunta não é sobre React, e sim sobre funções e módulos.

**1. A parte `export` se refere aos módulos**

[(Documentação da MDN sobre módulos)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Os módulos foram integrados ao ECMAscript/javascript há poucos anos, e decorrem da necessidade de maior organização de partes reutilizáveis de código que, antes, tinham que ser feitos com bibliotecas de terceiros ou referenciados com a tag `script`, que precisavam ser declaradas seguindo estritamente a ordem de dependências para seu script não quebrar.

Em síntese, você apresentou duas formas diferentes de disponibilizar um módulo: colocar o `export` antes do nome da função ou declarar a função normalmente e colocar os `export`s após o nome da função a ser exportada, ou todos juntos no final do módulo. O resultado é o mesmo, a diferença é só do ponto de vista de organização de código (que geralmente é um consenso da equipe que trabalha em um projeto; as grandes empresas costumam ter guias de estilo, e alguns até viram referência para além da empresa).

Portanto, quanto aos exports, as duas formas que você apresentou são idênticas.

Duas observações:

1. Um módulo pode ter mais de uma função ou variável exportada. A explicação refoge ao âmbito da pergunta, mas uma costuma (embora não seja obrigatório) ser marcada como `default`.
2. As opções de exportação têm o mesmo resultado, mas a importação não. É possível fazer a importação na raiz do módulo (nesse caso, o outro módulo será carregado de imediato), mas também é possível fazer a importação em locais posteriores do seu código, o que pode melhorar a performance (por exemplo, só importar uma biblioteca de frontend de ferramentas de admin se o usuário for um admin, etc). [Segue documentação (em inglês)](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports).

**2. A outra parte se refere a como declarar uma função**
[(Documentação da MDN sobre function expressions, com link para arrow functions)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function).

As duas primeiras formas que você apontou usam uma function expression; a terceira, uma arrow function. São apenas formas diferentes de declarar funções. A principal diferença é que, na arrow function (a terceira forma), a função não tem um contexto próprio e usa o contexto do lugar onde foi declarada; porém, se é um componente React declarado em um módulo, não fará diferença.

Observação: existe uma forma diferente de declarar um componente, aí sim seria uma pergunta típica do React: você pode ter componentes de classe e componentes funcionais. Todos os seus 3 exemplos são componentes funcionais (declarados mediante funções). Existe também a possibilidade de [declará-los como classes](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_class.asp). Essa era, inclusive, a única forma. Os componentes funcionais são relativamente recentes no React, e foram criados com a intenção de substituir os componentes de classe (embora isso *não seja* uma regra obrigatória, hoje em dia quem usa componentes de classe o faz por padronização quando tem um código legado, ou porque, por qualquer motivo, está mais familiarizado com eles, mas a tendência clara é usar componentes funcionais, e não de classe).

Portanto, sim: no âmbito do React, as três formas que você apontou são similares.

Answer (score 1):

Man, na verdade se resume a duas maneiras de exportar, basicamente é sobre o uso do `default`.

1. IMPLÍCITA:

```js
export default function Home() {
 // code...
}
```

onde você importa usando o nome que quiser, ex:

```js
import NomeQueQuiser from './home'
```

2. NOMEADA:

```js
export function Home() {
 // code...
}
```

já dessa maneira, o modo de importar o modulo/função muda, obrigando a utilizar o mesmo nome da função, inclusive podendo usar `destructuring`, ex:

```js
import { Home } from './home'
```

---

Sobre a forma que você declara a função, é indiferente para a exportação. ex:

```js
// declarativa (function declaration)
function Home () {}

// seta (arrow function)
const Home = () => {}
```

---

Espero ter ajudado, man!
abraço!